# Trouble with Cocoa Touch Threading

Tags: objective-c, ios, multithreading, nsnotificationcenter

I'm writing a multi threaded application for iOS.
I am new to Objective-C, so I haven't played around with threads in iPhone before.

Normally when using Java, I create a thread, and send "self" as object to thread. And from the thread I can therefor call the main thread.
How is this done in Objective C?

How can I call the main thread from a thread? I have been trying with NSNotificationCenter, but I get a sigbart error :/

This is how the thread is started:

```
NSArray *extraParams = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:savedUserName, serverInfo, nil];       // Parameters to pass to thread object

NSThread *myThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:statusGetter                      // New thread with statusGetter
                                             selector:@selector(getStatusFromServer:)   // run method in statusGetter
                                               object:extraParams];                     // parameters passed as arraylist
[myThread start];                                                                       // Thread started

activityContainerView.hidden = NO;
[activityIndicator startAnimating];
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you accomplish this by adding a message to the main thread's run loop.

Foundation provides some conveniences for this, notably  `-[NSObject performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:]` and `NSInvocation`.

using the former, you can simply write something like:

`[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateUI) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO]`

a notification may be dispatched from a secondary thread (often the calling thread).

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` or, if you're targeting iOS 4 and later, Grand Central Dispatch, which doesn't require you to implement a method just to synchronize with the main thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
    // Do stuff on the main thread here...
});
```

This often makes your code easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Though this is not a direct answer to your question I would highly recommend you take a look at [Grand Central Dispatch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html). It generally gives better performance than trying to use threads directly.

As Justin pointed out, you can always perform a function in the main thread by calling `performSelectorOnMainThread`, if you really needed too.